# PayPal API Pay Email Address Directly?

Tags: php, api, curl, paypal, paypal-ipn

One of the features on my site allows users to pay via PayPal for items from other users. I'm using the standard REST API since I had already made the code for another project a while ago, which works fine.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#create-a-payment

Currently, the page sends a 'v1/payments/payment' request which I execute to receive the money in to my PayPal account which created the access token. Is there a way I can directly get the user to pay another PayPal email address?

If not, I guess the only way is to do another request to pay the owner of the content from my PayPal once I receive the money - although it means PayPal get to charge a fee twice.

Thanks.